# Run two auto exit batch process without exiting command prompt after 1st process complete

Tags: powershell, batch-file, command, batch-processing

I am new in writing batch files on windows machine.

Here is the process

```
cd \
cd C:\bbCode
webpack --env=dev

cd \
cd C:\Project\bbCode
cordova run android --device
```

My problem is when `webpack` command run and when is finished, it exit the terminal without running next line of commands.

How to run other line of commands without exiting terminal after `webpack` is finished.

*Note : `webpack` and `cordova` are the commands to compile my code and build apk file respectively.

Answer (score 0):

assuming `webpack` is a batch file (you don't say...) then

```
CALL webpack --env=dev
```

Since `call` didn't work and `webpack` has unknown extension, then

```
start /wait "" webpack --env=dev
```

may fit the bill

Comment: Did you try the `call` anyway? What extension is `webpack`?

Comment: No I havent tried call. Give me a minute I will try and back to you. webpack is a module bundler. Its main purpose is to bundle JavaScript files for usage in a browser

Comment: It little help, like webpack is opening in new cmd when it finished it does not return to original cmd. https://imgur.com/a/ihrXMqK
You can look at the screenshot, so right side is the webpack is finished its job but left side cmd is still waiting for response of webpack process

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use EXIT command between two actions
CALL Action1
EXIT
CALL Action2

Instead of EXIT you can try :
EXIT /B 0